# Wrap unwrapped parts of HTML string with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, word-wrap

I have string in variable (Javascript/jQuery) containing content like this:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
<p>Morbi a faucibus magna. Donec lacinia, leo eget</p>
Pellentesque aliquet luctus lobortis.
<p>Morbi a faucibus magna. Donec lacinia, leo eget</p>
 massa iaculis leo, nec auctor
```

how i can wrap all unwrapped content in p tags?
So that string looks like:

```
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
<p>Morbi a faucibus magna. Donec lacinia, leo eget</p>
<p>Pellentesque aliquet luctus lobortis.</p>
<p>Morbi a faucibus magna. Donec lacinia, leo eget</p>
<p>massa iaculis leo, nec auctor</p>
```

Thank you!

Comment: Since this is a string of text, are there new line characters? How do you know when something should be wrapped?

Comment: There is no new line characters, just one continuous string. Basically  what needs to be wrapped is everything before first <p> tag, everything after last </p> tag, and everything between </p> and <p> (if exists any of that)..

Comment: @abdom: Okay. So where are you getting stuck?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I'm still learning JS so i didn't know how to write this, i was trying something with split and join but no luck.. This awnser from adeneo works great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like

```
var str = 'your string';
var div = $('<div />', {html: str});

div.contents().filter(function() {
    return this.nodeType === 3;
}).wrap('<p />');

var new_str = div.html();
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/jakgS/)

Using a new jQuery object to parse the string as HTML, and then filtering out unwrapped textnodes, and wrapping them with paragraphs, and outputting the changed HTML as the new string.

Comment: This works great! :) I'm still trying to figure out how it works as I'm new in JS :) Thank you!!

Comment: It works exactly like the added explanation says. It creates a jQuery object with the HTML as content, and then filters out textnodes and wraps them in paragraphs, and to get the altered HTML back it calls html()

Answer (score 0):

Here's a jQuery-free way to do it using only string methods (no DOM required.)

```
var text = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.<p>Morbi a faucibus magna. Donec lacinia, leo eget</p>Pellentesque aliquet luctus lobortis.<p>Morbi a faucibus magna. Donec lacinia, leo eget</p>massa iaculis leo, nec auctor",
    unwrapped = text.split(/<p>\b[^>]*<\/p>/g), //regex to split on all p wrapped text
    i;

for (i=0; i < unwrapped.length; i++) {
    text = text.replace(unwrapped[i], '<p>' + unwrapped[i] + '</p>');
};
```

Comment: [**TH̘Ë͖́̉ ͠P̯͍̭O̚​N̐Y̡ H̸̡̪̯ͨ͊̽̅̾̎Ȩ̬̩̾͛ͪ̈́̀́͘ ̶̧̨̱̹̭̯ͧ̾ͬC̷̙̲̝͖ͭ̏ͥͮ͟Oͮ͏̮̪̝͍M̲̖͊̒ͪͩͬ̚̚͜Ȇ̴̟̟͙̞ͩ͌͝S̨̥̫͎̭ͯ̿̔̀ͅ**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @adeneo I'm just exploiting a specific property of the posed text (the alternating of wrapped/unwrapped text), not descending into regex hell :P